# Google Load balancer with CDN for Internet NEGs not storing and using CDN cace

Tags: wordpress, caching, google-cloud-platform, cdn

I am using Google Cloud Load Balancing with CDN for optimizing load on my server and improving response time for static pages.

I was successfully able to set it up for serverless NEGs (AppEngine specifically) but I am unable to set it for internet NEGs.

#### ISSUE

The CDN does not cache the reponses from my WPEngine served website even with **Force cache all content** setting. The website is static (with php generated pages).
My WPEngine is already has caching with reverse proxy (can this be a problem?) but I wanted to optimize it even further Google's Edge infrastructure.

These are the caching headers with and without Google Load Balancer(with CDN).

#### Without Google Load Balancer

```
Server →nginx
Date →Wed, 11 Nov 2020 06:29:03 GMT
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Connection →keep-alive
Keep-Alive →timeout=20
Vary →Accept-Encoding
Vary →Accept-Encoding
Vary →Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Link →<https://xxxxxxxxx/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Powered-By →WP Engine
X-Cacheable →SHORT
Cache-Control →max-age=600, must-revalidate
X-Cache →HIT: 1
X-Cache-Group →normal
Content-Encoding →gzip
```

#### With Google Load Balancer(with CDN enabled)

```
Server →nginx
Date →Wed, 11 Nov 2020 06:30:01 GMT
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary →Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Link →<https://xxxxx-cdn.xxxxxx.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Powered-By →WP Engine
X-Cacheable →SHORT
X-Cache →MISS
X-Cache-Group →normal
Content-Encoding →gzip
Via →1.1 google
Alt-Svc →clear
Cache-Control →public,max-age=3600
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

The AGE header should be there for the CDN enabled request but it is missing showing a cache miss.